# Passing Array to REST get method

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to pass JSON array of objects as input parameter to @Controller get method. Here is example of array [{"longitude" : 231, "latitude" : 213, "start_time" : 2134 , "end time" : 2347, "description":"asd"},{"longitude" : 647, "latitude" : 435, "start_time" : 34 , "end time" : 788, "description":"zxcv"},...]. Is that possible?

Comment: It is uncommon to pass array as input *parameters*. But Spring MVC natively supports `@RequestBoby` and request body can be JSON. Would it be enough?

Comment: @SergeBallesta RequestBoby don't work with get requests

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I catch'd your question, but I'm using REST Spring MVC Controllers and i can give you a sample method i'm using.

```
public @ResponseBody
    List<MyObject> getMyObjectArray() {
        return myService.getMyObjectArray();
    }
```

This way you can respond to an Ajax Request with an ArrayList for example and Spring MVC will automatically treat it as a JSON

Comment: Not realy. Array should be input parameter not a returning clouse